# Data transfer from Azure event hub to Azure Redis Cache

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub, azure-redis-cache

We've have product data in Azure event hub which is coming from external system, now our requirement is to send this data to Azure Redis cache from event hub.

Is there any Out of the box way or standard function in Azure to implement it.

Thanks,
Kuldeep

Comment: But as of today there is no OOB trigger function for redis cache.

Answer (score 1):

There is no out-of-the-box support, but it should be very easy to achieve this with an [EventHub-triggered Azure Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs) that writes into Redis.

Comment: But as of today there is no OOB trigger function for redis cache.

Comment: Well that’s what I wrote. You have to build this yourself. But since there are SDKs for redis, this really should be not big issue at all.